# Objects are made invisible in Final Render because of Modifiers

Tags: rendering

I have a basic setup of a scene. The issue I am encountering is that when I go to do my final render, many objects are missing and random streaks of light appear on the screen.

I have already ruled out the issue of not having the little camera icon enabled. All objects should be visible in the final render.

**Here is an image of the scene with Eevee:**

[image]

**Here is what the image looks like in the final F12 render, also in Eevee**

[image]

**Here is me showing that I have told blender to render all objects**

[image]

What is wrong with my scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your difference are these two little cute icons here:

[image]

As you can see, you switched the modifier off for viewport, but you put it on for render. That's why you see the difference. You don't have to delete it. Just put both on or both off to get the same result for render + viewport.